# Is it possible to edit rendered markdown (in flutter)?

Tags: android, flutter, markdown

I'm working on a notes app in flutter, and I want it such that the user can interact with rendered markdown by default. For example, the user types in whatever they want into a text box then they can select text and tap buttons on the screen to alter the selected text (e.g. a button to make it bold, a button to make it a header, a button to create a table). Think a word document

Is it at all possible? Whether that's with markdown or with a different plugin

I tried using the flutter_markdown plugin but it only lets you select the rendered markdown, it doesn't let you edit it. I also tried looking at other apps (namely, [FlutterMarkdownEditor](https://github.com/adityar224/FlutterMarkdownEditor)), but no luck